# Macro in pgAdmin - get number of rows for query

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

In pgAdmin, you can define your own [macro](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.8/macros.html) with `'$SELECTION$'` placeholder. I have a macro to count number of rows in table:

```
select count(*) as rows_in_table from $SELECTION$;
```

This works well, but as I write a lot of queries at work I tought it would be nice to have macro to count rows for any select statement. The only way I found is to create function where two different situation are handled - only table name is selected or query is selected:

```
create or replace function sys.number_of_rows(in sql text)
  returns table (number_of_rows bigint) as
$body$
    begin
      sql:= 
        case 
          when position(' ' in trim(sql)) = 0 then 'select count(*) from ' || sql 
          else 'select count(*) from (' || sql || ') a ' end;
      return query execute sql;
    end;
$body$
  language plpgsql;
```

Now with macro `select sys.number_of_rows('$SELECTION$');` I can pass either table name or whole query.

This works perfectly, but only when the function `sys.number_of_rows` exists in database. Any idea how to achieve the same functionality without being dependent on function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace `$SELECTION$` with `( $SELECTION$ ) as t` it should also work when your selection is a complete query.

I don't use pgAdmin, but my SQL client supports the same replacement technique and I use the same kind of macro there.

Comment: Is it SQL Workbench you are using?

Comment: @TomasGreif: yes, that's the tool ;)